# Here Maps Size on Wordpress and HTML

Tags: html, wordpress, resize, here-api

We are trying to insert Here Maps form http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/api-explorer. We've tried the basic map and Search and display multiple addresses in a web that uses Wordpress and in a web that works with HTML in both cases we experienced the same issue: Here Maps take up all the web page. any idea to solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can apply styles to their iframe. Usually it's #np_liveviewFrame. So your code will look like:

```
#np_liveviewFrame {
width:1200px;
}
```

You'll need to correct positioning in that case also.

Comment: @merxe use Pavel's style in your styles.css and if it doesn't work try adding the width to #mapContainer instead of #np_liveviewFrame